# The easiest way to turn the bulge of the mesh outwards

Tags: mesh, transforms

Do you know any way to efficiently reverse the convexity of this mesh to the outside?
I mean the part created after the boolean operation.
Thanks for the suggestions.

[image]

Comment: can you share the blend file? https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: you could try selecting those faces and going to *Mesh > Convex Hull* to straighten it out, and then use [Propertional Editing](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/proportional_editing.html) to buldge them outwards

Comment: Blend file:
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=ywKBwG68" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/ywKBwG68/)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Assuming the blue loops are lying flat in a plane, you can try the following:

- create a face which which is lying in that said plane (select 3 vertices for example and right-click -> `New Edge/Face from Vertices`)
- separate that face, create an `Empty` and snap that empty with snap options `Face Project` and `Align Rotation to Target`
- separate your concave geometry and add a `Mirror` modifier to it, choose the empty  as the mirror object and set the mirror options appropiatly, you should now see the convex geometry you want
- apply, cleanup, join back

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The presented situation is only an example, in other situations the shapes will be more complicated, so a mirror will unfortunately not work. I'm still looking for a way to simulate the mirror effect, but from the point of view of individual polygons - I don't know how understandable it is :)

Comment: I think i understand. You need a way for some kind of mirror surface which is not flat but bends along some set of to-be-mirrored polygon stripes. Maybe update or ask a new question with a concrete example showing the complication in detail.